# How can I iterate over an array of URLs and use them as image sources based on the index value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

I want to display the image that is in the array of strings mentioned in the interface. I am getting the array of image URLs from the fetching the API that is in another component. Also I want the source the links it contains now to be the default link.

I haven't been able to experiment much since the API is costing me. I have tried using a state and `onError` function however in state it only takes one image and upon changing  it changes the whole thing and has only one image.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface imageType{
  urlimage:string[];
} 

function ImageDisplay(props:any) {
  return (
  <>
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 p-4 gap-2">
      <img alt="gallery" className="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).webp" />
      <img alt="gallery" className="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(74).webp" />
      <img alt="gallery" className="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(75).webp" />
      <img alt="gallery" className="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(76).webp" />
      <img alt="gallery" className="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(77).webp" />
      <img alt="gallery" className="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(78).webp" />
    </div>
  </>
)} 

export default ImageDisplay;
```

Comment: Do you want have a default image and when image loaded it shows instead ?

Comment: Why aren't you using the standard [`map()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) approach?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "I want the source the links it contains now to be the default link". Please revise to clarify.

Comment: So the links above are the default images and , I have a state that contains links for 6 URLs that are images , and I want it to iterate and in the src use those images if it is null then use the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly you want an Image for every URL you have in the array?

That would be that:

```
function ImageDisplay({imageUrls}: ImageType) {
  return imageUrls.map((url) => <img alt="gallery" className="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg" src={url}/>
) }}
```

Comment: So the links above are the default images and , I have a state that contains links for 6 URLs that are images , and I want it to iterate and in the src use those images if it is null then use the default. Something like this so totally I have 6 rectangles that are displaying the image.

Comment: Also yess the above given ans is half of it. However I am still confused as to how do I have 6 different default images that would kick in if one of the images fail

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You can always extend a type defining a fallback. ImageType is then an object containing the url and the static fallback image. And if the url mapped is undefined you can use the ??-operator to use the fallback url.